# passing php array to Ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Hi all I know there is a few results on this topic but I am not trying to do anything too advanced just yet trying to understand the basics. For some reason this code the alert works and prints out the correct array information but I can't seem to get it working for the autocomplete? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
oReq.onload = function() {
    var res = oReq.responseText;
    AC(res);
};
oReq.open("get", "get-data.php", false);
oReq.send();

function AC(res){
$(function() {
    alert(res);
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: res
    });
});
}
```

so the alert(res) is working in function AC() but it's still not populating the source?

my get-data.php looks like this

```
<?php $arr = array("ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp");

echo json_encode($arr); ?>
```

I'd appreciate any guidance even if I have to look up more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.unserialize in javascript.

```
source: JSON.parse(res);
```

This happens due to not decoded JSON.
JSON arrives as string, so that alert() works properly presenting the received data, however when you post to source, you have to post Object - requires to decode string into object. ;)
The Resulting code:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
oReq.onload = function() {
    var res = oReq.responseText;
    AC(res);
};
oReq.open("get", "get-data.php", false);
oReq.send();

function AC(res){
$(function() {
    alert(res);
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: JSON.parse(res)
    });
});
}
```

HTH

Comment: Hi Valentin, thanks for your quick response. I tried the line you suggested thinking it all made sense but still not working for me :( is there anything else you can think of?

Comment: post your code below as different case of problem ;)

Comment: Hi Valentin i got it working with JSON.parse thanks for your logical help though :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad :( JSON.parse(). anyways, the logic within ^_^